# Web application without libraries | Relation to job postings

Tags: web-development, skills

I have an application built without any libraries using PHP, JavaScript, HTML5, CSS, and mySQL that will support major modern browsers - IE, Safari, FF, Opera, and Chrome.

One thing I've noticed is that most web jobs 90%+ ask for library experience of some sort.

About 10 % do not... they focus more on the language then language-libraries.

Why this lean toward libraries? I can understand that you don't want to have to re-write AES encryption algorithms and PHd level math things like that, but so much web development does not have any high level math at all.

What is the difference between jobs that focus on library use vs. jobs that focus on language?

Comment: Uh because who the hell wants to pay our wages reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @Rig - Pretty much hit the nail on the head. That and 90%+ of experienced web devs will be at least somewhat familiar with a couple of frameworks in their given language.

Comment: The job listings that don't ask for library experience just assume that you'll be good enough to pick up the libraries. They don't actually mean they're not using libraries.

Comment: You claim you wrote an application without using any "libraries" this makes me wonder how much work you had to do, to avoid using a library, to make your own job easier.

Comment: My app is for IE9+ and modern versions of FF, Safari, and Chrome....so it was not that difficult.  Not supporting IE8 and below cuts out a lot of cross browser code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ninety percent of all software applications that are being written by software developers earning a paycheck are line-of-business CRUD applications... unspectacular software that models business processes.  These are domains where the process of developing software is already very well-understood, and libraries have emerged as a way to speed up the development of mundane, repetitive elements such as database access, data validation and the like.

Consequently, most employers expect developers with current knowledge of programming practices to know and understand these "tools of the trade," since it costs a lot of time, effort and money to reproduce that which has already been adequately created by someone else.

As to the other ten percent of software applications (those involving research or specialized domains such as aerospace), there is still a significant demand for custom code, as the problems posed by such environments do not always lend themselves well to the stitching together of generalized libraries.

Comment: I'm transitioning from what I would call personal project to professional.  Most of my initiatives have been innovative - client side modeling of sessions, modification of the MVC ( things that might annoy, alarm dogma based companies ), etc., oddly I will probably re-write a standard based version of my app using Zend and jQuery, etc. so I can compare my work against "standards"

Comment: People who write libraries and other work-saving tools are even more valuable than the people who use those tools to write apps.  It requires significant *expertise* to write a tool that has a decent API, is useable in a wide variety of scenarios, and avoids breaking the bank from a memory/performance standpoint.